# react bootstrap: navbar last item right-hand positioning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bootstrap-4, alignment, navbar

I want to use Bootstrap and React to make the same menu as in the top image.

[image]

But no matter what alignment you put, you get a menu like on the bottom image.

[image]

the current sources looks like this:

```
 <Navbar expand="sm" bg="light" className="w-50 general_menu">
  <Nav>
   <Nav.Link className="active">Left One</Nav.Link>
   <Nav.Link>Left Two</Nav.Link>
   <Nav.Link>Left Three</Nav.Link>
   <Nav.Link className="border-left pl-2">Right One</Nav.Link>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

Tell me please, what changes do I have to make to place the navmenu last item as in the top image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply css to `Right One` link: `margin-left: auto` or add class `ml-auto` to Last link:

```
<Nav.Link className="border-left pl-2 ml-auto">Right One</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: did not work :( `<Nav.Link className="border-left pl-2" style={{"margin-left": "auto"}}>` and `<Nav.Link className="border-left pl-2 ml-auto">`

Comment: the parent which is wrapping this component should be flex. If it still doesn't work then maybe create a reproducible example on codesandbox and paste the link here.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/MotherlyFragrantClass, i use container-fluid `<div className="container-fluid min-vh-100 bg-dark">
      <div className = 'ml-auto row justify-content-center bg-dark'><GeneralMenu />/div></div>`

Comment: big thanks!!! `<Nav className="container-fluid">` instead `<Nav>`

Comment: Note in boostrap 5 you need `ms-auto` in stead of `ml-auto`

Answer (score -1):

Use inside left-side navbar css class `mr-auto`.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="navbar-text">
Place your right side element here
</span>
```

This code get from original [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#text).
[image: navbar sample]

Comment: this code will put all the items to the right, and I only need to put one item to the right and the rest to the left.